# Site search plus google search

Tags: search

I am searching for a way to have the drupal search pull up pages from the drupal site PLUS search results from google in general (not site specific search). Does anyone know some direction how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with this two [Google Site Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/gss) & [Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_cse) modules.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a way to search all of google, not just specific sites. (it looks like there might be a way with adsence which I am investigating)